# Class garbage collection with Task

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, task-parallel-library

I have a class MyClass that runs a Task:

```
MyClass
{
   Run()
   {
      Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
      {
         while(true) { }
      }
   }
}
```

Now let's say at one point of the program the instance of this class has no more references.

```
Main()
{
   var instance = new MyClass();
   instance.Run();

   Sleep(1000); // buy some time

   instance = new MyClass(); // the previous instance has no more references

   bla bla bla code ...
}
```

Now what's the behaviour of the first instace of MyClass? Is it ready to be garbage collected or it will live forever because of the task?

Comment: You don't do yourself a favor by posting such an unrealistic example.  The Run() method should be *static*, no point in creating an object of MyClass at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on what exactly does the lambda inside `Task.Factory.StartNew()` do.

If it's something like your example and it doesn't reference any instance members of the class, then this means the lambda delegate (which is referenced by the `Task`) doesn't reference the instance of your class, so the instance is eligible for garbage collection.

On the other hand, if the lambda accessed any instance members of the class, the lambda will [close over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) `this`. This means that the delegate will reference the instance, so the instance won't be garbage collected.

But in real code, you usually shouldn't need to think about this (unless you're investigating a memory leak). The GC will keep objects that can still be used alive and collect the rest, which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your task does not reference any object. It is not referenced by any object. `MyClass` is a red herring in your sample code. It has no influence on the question whether unreferenced tasks are garbage collected.

Unreferenced delegate-based tasks are not garbage collected until they have been executed. (Except for crazy `TaskScheduler`'s that just drop tasks).